# Rational representations and Chevalley bases

Tags: representation-theory, algebraic-groups, linear-groups

Let $G$ be a semi-simple linear algebraic group over $\mathbb{C}$ and $\rho\colon G \to \operatorname{GL}_{\mathbb{C}}(V)$ be a finite-dimesional irreducible rational representation of $G$.

Being a linear group, one can talk about the $\mathbb{Z}$-points of $G$: $G(\mathbb{Z}) = G\cap \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$ if $G \leq \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$. As algebraic groups, we have the extension of scalars $G = G(\mathbb{Z}) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{C}$ -- if I understand correctly this is true because we can recover $G(\mathbb{Z})$ by applying the construction of the Universal Chevalley Group to the Lie algebra of $G$ and then killing out a central subgroup determined by the root lattices.

Now, given this rational representation, can we always find a lattice $V_{\mathbb{Z}}$ such that $\rho$ is the extension of scalars of a rational representation $G(\mathbb{Z}) \to \operatorname{GL}_{\mathbb{Z}}(V_{\mathbb{Z}})$?

I'm not very familiar with the Chevalley constructions, but if I understand correctly one first builds special bases to complex semisimple Lie algebras to obtain a lattice called Chevalley bases, and then applying the exponential formulas to this base in order to find a linear algebraic group. One then checks that the elements in the Chevalley bases of the Lie algebra gets sent to integral elements in the algebraic group. Given the construction of the irreducible rational representations by Verma modules, I would suppose one could repeat this procedure to construct the map $G(\mathbb{Z}) \to \operatorname{GL}_{\mathbb{Z}}(V_{\mathbb{Z}})$, but I couldn't find a reference as I'm not sure I'm searching the right terms.

Comment: What if some $\rho(g)$ has an eigenvalue which is not an algebraic integer? (I'm not sure if this can actually happen, I don't know much about this topic)

Comment: @LukasHeger this is a very good point. In fact, my question seems almost equivalent to asking whether every rational representation over $\mathbb{C}$ is conjugate to one where the rational functions are actually polynomials with integer coefficients, which would imply all eigenvalues are indeed algebraic integers. From my calculations, we can always find $V_{\mathbb{Z}}$ for $SL_2$ and $SL_3$, but that's because we have a fairly explicit description. I'm trying to see if there is a more explicit answer in SGA 3, but it's being a slow process.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, from the proof of Theorem 39(e) and the remark thereafter in Steinberg's _Lectures in Chevalley Groups_ we get the existence of a rational form $G(\mathbb{Q}) \to \operatorname{GL}_{\mathbb{Q}}(V_{\mathbb{Q}})$. This is basically because of the "functoriality'' of the Chevalley group construction I was searching for at the end of the question, that is, the fact that an inclusion of root lattices of a representation induces a rational homomorphism of algebraic groups defined over the prime field (Corollary 1 to Theorem 7 in the same book).